# Connection/Consistency Between Different Definitions of Polyhedron? And How Does This Proof Apply to This Definition?

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, proof-explanation, affine-geometry, polyhedra

My textbook gives the following definition of a polyhedron:

> A *polyhedron* is defined as the solution set of a finite number of linear equalities and inequalities:
>
> $$\mathcal{P} = \{ x \mid a^T_j x \le b_j, \ j = 1, \dots , m, \ c_j^T x = d_j, \ j = 1, \dots , p \}$$
>
> A polyhedron is thus the intersection of a finite number of halfspaces and hyperplanes.  Affine set (e.g., subspaces, hyperplanes, lines), rays, line segments, and halfspaces are all polyhedra. It is easily shown that polyhedra are convex set.

I was trying to find a proof of the fact that polyhedra are convex sets, and so I came across [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1996738/every-polyhedron-is-convex-setproof-explanation):

> Let $\mathrm{\mathbf{a}}$ be a vector and let $b$ a scalar. Suppose that $\mathrm{\mathbf{x}}$ and $\mathrm{\mathbf{y}}$ satisfy $\mathrm{\mathbf{a}}' \mathrm{\mathbf{x}} \ge b$ and $\mathrm{\mathbf{a}}' \mathrm{\mathbf{y}} \ge b$, respectively, and therefore belong to the same halfspace. Let $\lambda \in [0, 1]$. Then, $\mathrm{\mathbf{a}}'(\lambda \mathrm{\mathbf{x}} + (1 - \lambda)\mathrm{\mathbf{y}}) \ge \lambda b+ (1 - \lambda)b = b$, which proves that $\lambda \mathrm{\mathbf{x}} +(1 - \lambda) \mathrm{\mathbf{y}}$ also belongs to the same halfspace. Therefore a halfspace is convex. Since a polyhedron is the intersection of a finite number of halfspaces, the result follows from part (a).

The author provides a proof of this fact in his own question. However, after trying to understand this proof, a number of questions arose:

1. The proof starts by supposing that $\mathrm{\mathbf{a}}' \mathrm{\mathbf{x}} \ge b$ and $\mathrm{\mathbf{a}}' \mathrm{\mathbf{y}} \ge b$. But, in the above definition of a polyhedron, it is said that $\mathcal{P} = \{ x \mid a^T_j x \le b_j, \ j = 1, \dots , m, \ c_j^T x = d_j, \ j = 1, \dots , p \}$; in other words, we have that $a^T_j x \le b_j, \ j = 1, \dots , m$, instead of $a^T_j x \ge b_j$, which it seems is what the proof has?
2. The above definition also has the set condition $c_j^T x = d_j, \ j = 1, \dots , p$. Is this equivalent to $\mathrm{\mathbf{a}}'(\lambda \mathrm{\mathbf{x}} + (1 - \lambda)\mathrm{\mathbf{y}}) \ge \lambda b+ (1 - \lambda)b = b$ in the proof?
3. The proof says that "Since a polyhedron is the intersection of a finite number of halfspaces, ...". What about the hyperplanes? I see no mention of them in the proof.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**On question 1**: It is frequently the case that the same definition can be expressed in multiple ways. In this case, you can define a polyhedron as

$$\mathcal{P} = \{ x \mid a^T_j x \le b_j, \ j = 1, \dots , m, \ c_j^T x = d_j, \ j = 1, \dots , p \}$$

Or you can define it as

$$\mathcal{P} = \{ x \mid a^T_j x \ge b_j, \ j = 1, \dots , m, \ c_j^T x = d_j, \ j = 1, \dots , p \}$$

Notice that , if you plug the same $a$ and $b$ in these two definitions, you will get different polyhedra. But that is because $a$ and $b$ themselves mean slightly different things in both definitions. In particular, whenever the author of the first definition would use $a$, the author of the second would use $-a$.

For example, consider a 2D space, $\mathbb{R}^2$, and let's focus on the polyhedron that is to the right on the line $x=1$.

One author can denote this polyhedron as $\{(x, y)|x\ge 1\}$. Another author may write $\{(x, y)|-x\le -1\}$. Regardless of which notation you choose, you're denoting the same polyhedron.

**On questions 2 and 3:** Hyperplanes make things easier sometimes, but you can define a polyhedron simply as the intersection of half-spaces. You can simply replace each hyperplane of the kind $cx=d$ with two half-spaces, $cx \geq d$ and $cx \leq d$. Therefore, anything that works for intersection of half-spaces also works for intersection of half-spaces and hyperplanes.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to question 1, if you negate $a$ and $b$, you obtain $-a^Tx\le -b$.

For questions 2 and 3, a hyperplane is the intersection of the closed halfspaces it bounds.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. With regards to question 1, isn't $-a^Tx\le -b$ different from $a^Tx\le b$?

Comment: Um, sorry. It's of the proper form. It doesn't mean the same thing, but the set of possible constraints is the exact same.

Comment: Hmm, what does it mean to say that "the set of possible constraints is the same"? How is it relevant in this context?

Comment: Every constraint of the form $ax\le b$ is equivalent to a constraint of the form $ax\ge b$, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

(1) you do not need to be worry about that. Since both $a_i$ and $b_i$ are arbitrary, then you can define the equivalent form $-a^T_jx\ge -b_j$ to the standard form $a_j^Tx\le b_j$ and define  some $a'$ and $b'$ for which $a'_j=-a_j$ and $b'_j=-b_j$ such that$$a'^T_jx\ge b'_j$$ (2) as any equality $p=q$ can be expressed by two simultaneous inequalities $p\le q$ and $p\ge q$ or $p\le q $ and $-p\le -q$ therefore any $c^T_jx=d_j$ can be expressed similarly with $-c^T_jx\le -d_j$ and $c^T_jx\le d_j$ and treated to just like the other inequalities of the standard form $a_j^Tx\le b_j$. **More generally, you can define a polyhedron as follows:$$\mathcal{P} = \{ x \mid a^T_j x \le b_j, \ j = 1, \dots , m\}$$because a set of inequalities is a generalized form of set of equalities** as shown just before.

(3) we have already answered this part in (2), but we mention it once more here for sake of completeness. Any equation of the form $$c^Tx=d$$ (which is also referred to as hyper-plane) is equivalent to two half-spaces as follows $$c^Tx\le d\\-c^Tx\le -d$$which yields to an important result: **any hyper-plane is equivalent to exactly two half-spaces**

P.S. it is highly recommended to check out the below resource on convex sets

http://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/

which contains definitions and very nice approaches to convex sets and I think they meet your needs.